# knitr: object cannot be found when converting markdown file into html

Tags: r, knitr

Hi I am using R studio and the "knitHTML" button to convert my Rmd file into a html file. However, even thought the code runs fine, when using knitHTML it cannot find any of my objects previously created:

```
## Error: object 'cbt_2010' not found
```

however if I type cbt_2010 at the terminal - it is there. Bascially knit cannot find any of the objects in the workspace.

what am I doing wrong? it just seems any data produced in each chunk is lost in memory when using knit!

Comment: I believe knit opens its own R session, it's best for reproducibility

Comment: if you want to knit based on the objects in the current session (a possibly bad idea as @baptiste suggests), just `library(knitr); knit2html("<filename>")` in the console.

Comment: I think I face today a similar problem as @AleksandrBlekh. How to debug further this one?

Comment: Was a typo in my case!

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh when you load/read an object, even in-line, how do you check if it's there?  Can you `str(object)` and/or else, like `summary(object)`?

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh Anyway, somehow it'll work. Did you resolve your problem?  I was trying to give a hand actually :-) Maybe we can continue in a chat session, in case. And remove unnecessary comments here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117322/discussion-between-nikos-alexandris-and-aleksandr-blekh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned by @BenBolker , you can use `knit2html`( Note that it is different from the Rstudio button, Rstudio use its own function to process document) from `knitr`:

````
 x <- 10
 writeLines(c("# hello markdown",
          "```{r hello-random, echo=TRUE}", 
               "rnorm(x)", "```"), ## note the use of x
 "test.Rmd")
 library(knitr)
 knit2html("test.Rmd")
````

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something in your question, but if you create object 'cbt_2010' in your .Rmd file, knitr will have that object to work with.

Stated differently, you can find it when you type object 'cbt_2010' at the console because you created that object and it is available to R.  You need to do the same in the .Rmd file.