# xTable Error inspite of object in memory

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, xtable

Created a Data Frame `ofp.1` which contains 13 rows and 2 columns using normal R file. The Data Frame is present in memory .

Now I want to use this table in xtable to print in R Markdown file.

````
`---
title: "abc"
output: html_document

---


<table border = 1 align='center'>
<tr>
<td  style='text-align:center'>
```{r include=FALSE}
    library(xtable)
```
```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}

  print(xtable(ofp.1),type='html',include.rownames=F)
```
</td>
</tr>
</table>
````

I am getting error `Error in xtable(ofp.1) : object 'ofp.1' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> print -> xtable
Execution halted`

what i Can figure out is that Markdown cannot find my Table though it is present in memory. Need Help .Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [knitr: object cannot be found when converting markdown file into html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364408/knitr-object-cannot-be-found-when-converting-markdown-file-into-html)

Comment: In order for your document to be reproducible, you should not do what you are attempting.

Comment: @ThomasK the same code is working for mtcars and other inbuilt data

Comment: So what? All datasets like `iris` or `mtcars` are shipping with the base-package: `datasets`, which is automatically added to your search path, when you start `R`. Your object is not a built-in dataset, therefore a fresh `r-session` (which `knitr` uses to construct your document) won't find your object since `.GlobalEnv` will be empty.

Comment: You would need to define `ofp.1` somewhere in your `.Rmd` inside of a code-chunk.

Comment: @ThomasK I  saved the data frame as .Rda file and loaded the same in Rmd file . Its working now.