# Getting knit r to recognize objects

Tags: r

I'm having the problem referenced here:

[knitr: object cannot be found when converting markdown file into html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364408/knitr-object-cannot-be-found-when-converting-markdown-file-into-html)

I do not understand how to fix it. How do I link the .R code to the .Rmd knit r doc to stop the error?

I placed all associated code in the knit r doc and hit "Knit HTML" and got the error message below.

```
> require(knitr); knit('test.Rmd', encoding='');
Loading required package: knitr


processing file: test.Rmd
Error in parse_block(g[-1], g[1], params.src) : 
  duplicate label 'raw_data'
Calls: knit ... process_file -> split_file -> lapply -> FUN -> parse_block
Execution halted

knitr terminated with status 1
```

Comment: I don’t understand at all what you’re asking. Please be explicit about your question, and state the expected output and actual output. And what is “the .R file”?

Answer (score 1):

When I need to "run extra code" I set sections of R code with the option `echo` to `FALSE`. The code I want to display I turn `echo` back to `TRUE` in a separate code chunk. If you want to include code in a knitr document that is not going to be run, you can set `eval` to `FALSE`. Or you can use the HTML markdown to write it yourself with monospace, indented font.